# How to set value extractor and labels in GCP log-based metric via python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, logging

I'm trying to programmatically create log-based metrics using [Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/logging/latest/metric), but can't figure out how to extract values from the filter via regex -- in the UI, this would be the `Field Name` and `Regular Expression` inputs under the filter selection for Distribution metrics, and just Labels for Counter metrics. Basically everything after the Build Filter in the UI:

[image]

It seems the `ValueExtractor` field exists (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/projects.metrics#LogMetric), but I haven't been able to figure out if it's surfaced/how to access it if so.

The following is the skeleton code I can use to create a metric without a value extractor or labels:

```
from google.cloud import logging

client = logging_v2.Client(project=<PROJECT>)
metric = logging.Metric(client=client,
                        name=<NAME>,
                        description=<DESCRIPTION>,
                        filter_=<GCP LOG EXPRESSION>)
metric.create(client=client)
```